# PowerShell replace value in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, arrayofarrays

I'm quite new in PowerShell and I would need a little bit of support how to replace values in an array. Please have a look at my example:

```
[array[]]$nodes = @()
[array[]]$nodes = get-NcNode | select-object -property Node, @{Label = "slot"; expression = {@("a")*4}}

$nodes
Node       slot
----       ----
nn01       {a,a,a,a}
nn02       {a,a,a,a}
nn03       {a,a,a,a}
nn04       {a,a,a,a}             
 
$nodes[0].slot[0]
      a

$nodes[0].slot[0] = "b"            #I try to replace a with b
$nodes[0].slot[0]
      a                            #It didn’t work

$nodes[0].slot.SetValue("b",0)     #I try to replace a with b
$nodes[0].slot[0]
      a                            #It didn’t work

$nodes[0] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name slot[0] -Value "b" -Force
$nodes[0]
Node       slot      slot[0]
----       ----      -------
nn01       {a,a,a,a} b              #That’s not what I wanted
```

Comment: `$nodes[0].slot[0] = "b" ` works fine for me. Note that the `$nodes` array is not inline with your `Select-Object` expression. If the slot is an array, there should be spaces between the strings in the display output: `{a, a, a, a}`. I recommend you to use this `$Nodes = 1..4 | Select-Object @{n = 'Node'; e = { "nn0$_" }}, @{n = 'Slot'; e = { @('a') * 4 }}` for the [MCVE] input.

Comment: As an aside: The initialization statement, `[array[]]$nodes = @()`, is pointless: its effects are replaced by the next `[array[]]$nodes = ...` statement.

Comment: @iRon, the code only works if `[array[]]` is changed to `[array]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need an *array of arrays* (type `[array[]]`), your problem is solved as follows:

```sh
$nodes[0][0].slot[0] = "b"
```

That is, each of your `$nodes` elements is itself an array, and the way you filled `$nodes`, each `[pscustomobject]` instance output by your `get-NcNode | select-object ...` pipeline became its own element of `$nodes`, but each *as a single-element sub-array* - hence the need for the extra `[0]` index access.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

However, it sounds like a regular array (`[array]`, effectively the same as `[object[]]`) is sufficient in your case, where each element holds a (single, scalar) `[pscustomobject]`:

```sh
# Type constraint [array] creates a regular [object[]] array.
[array] $nodes = get-NcNode | select-object -property Node, @{Label = "slot"; expression = {@("a")*4}}
```

With `$nodes` defined like this, your original code should work.

---

<sup>[1] On *getting* a value - but not on *setting* - you can get away without the extra index, thanks to PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature.</sup>